# Node js Debugger in Visual studio code is not letting me debug by hitting the api url

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I may be  unaware about the debugging in VS code tool. I am trying to debug my typescript  code using Nodejs debugger. But, I expect that as soon as I click on Debug play button the server of my code should start on some port , so that I could after that start hitting api through POSTMAN &  then debug it on VS code . But, what happens is that as soon as I click on Debug Play button, the control comes to my set break point & then I keep on stepping over until it reaches to last line of server port ignition & then server just starts in Debug mode. After this, I try hitting the api url from POSTMAN which successfully shows the response on POSTMAN itself. But, Nothing happens on my Debug console. There is no show on Variable values.Absolutely nothing... Can anyone please help me what I'm doing wrong here... I also tried Debug with chrome but it is throwing error in launching the chrome app itself & I am unable to figure out this Debug with chrome issue also. Well below is my launch.json script for Node Debugger .

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node_Debug_launch",            
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\source\\server.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the behaviour of my VSCode after it ends up starting server with all the step overs done & also api url is hit from the POSTMAN with proper success response received in POSTMAN itself.
[image: No effect after after hitting API from POSTMAN]

Comment: You should set breakpoints inside the controller

Comment: I changed the breakpoint from putting it in end of controller to putting it in the function where I want to check & yes the server got started  beforehand itself(it helped). But, then when I'm hitting from postman the  screen remains same like the image which  I have pasted before.

Comment: So maybe the controller never runs